# inject version to DLLs during build process

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, jenkins, wix, versioning

this is my situation:

1. I have VS2010 solution with X projects included.
2. Wix project that can create msi from all compiled artifacts.
3. I have build machine \ Jenkins that first compile (MSBuild .Net 4) all the solution, then compile the wix to package it to msi.

What\how can I inject to **all artifacts\dlls** the number of the product (e.g 11.2.0.4789) - as simple as possible?

Is there and command line arguments that can be passed while compiling the solution?

Comment: If you are going to use that version format as the msi version be  aware that Windows Installer will ignore the fourth part, which could cause problems upgrading if only the fourth part is changed. See [ProductVersion property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370859(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 6):

There are tools, such as several extensions for MSBuild, that do version stamping but each assumes a particular workflow. You might find one that works for you but a DIY method would help you evaluate them, even if it isn't your final solution.

You can add a property to the MSBuild command-line like this:

```
msbuild /p:VersionStamp=11.2.0.4789
```

Note: I assume you are going to parameterize the Jenkins build in some way or generate the number during a preceding build step. Here is a simulation of that:

```
echo 11.2.0.4789 >version.txt
set /p version=reading from pipe <version.txt
msbuild /p:VersionStamp=%version%
```

Now, the work is in getting each project to use it. That would depend on the project type and where you want VersionStamp to appear.

For a csproj, you might want to use it as the AssemblyVersion. The simplest way is to move the attribute to a cs file by itself and rewrite it every time. I would leave a comment in AssemblyInfo.cs as a clue to where it now comes from. You can include the cs file in your project either dynamically or permanently. I prefer dynamically since it is effectively an intermediate file for the build. So, in your .csproj add the following in a text editor (e.g. Visual Studio. Unload and Edit project):

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <AssemblyVersionPath>$(IntermediateOutputDir)AssemblyVersion.cs</AssemblyVersionPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Include="$(AssemblyVersionPath)" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <WriteLinesToFile
      File='$(AssemblyVersionPath)' 
      Overwrite="true"
      Condition="'$(ProductVersion)' != ''"
      Lines='using System.Reflection%3b;&#x0a;[assembly: AssemblyVersion("$(VersionStamp)")]' />
  </Target>
```

This is sufficient but a more thorough solution would include adding the file to a list so it is cleaned with other files and only writing the file if the version changed to prevent unnecessary rebuilds, etc.

Use a similar technique for other project types.

Comment: Worked perfectly! 
Just modified the conditions a bit as my CI builds the files under a different configuration. 
Thanks!